# Image onload trigger's immidately

Tags: jquery, image, onload

I have created a lightbox which loads images from the gallery, when image is clicked(one at a time). The problem is that image doesn't load and hence the dimension of the image is not known. Here is code:

```
function showimage(image_path) {
    imgobj = new Image();
    imgobj.src = image_path;
    var aspectratio = imgobj.width/imgobj.height;
    var newht = imgobj.height;
    var newwd = imgobj.width;
    if (($(window).height() - 100) < newht) {
        newht = $(window).height() - 100;
        newwd = newht*aspectratio;
    }
    if (($(window).width() - 100) < newwd) {
        newwd = $(window).width() - 100;
        newht = newwd/aspectratio;
    }
    $('#lightbox img').attr('height', newht);
    $('#lightbox img').attr('width', newwd);
    $('#lightbox').show();
}
```

I tried using onLoad, but that triggers immediately and image is still not loaded and doesnt give proper image dimension. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077890/image-onload-event-triggering-before-its-image-fully-loaded) I read that when the image is already loaded in the browser, onLoad is called instantly.

Everywhere else people have suggested to use time delay "setTimeout", but that doesnt seems a good solution as the images can be of different sizes and can take variable time to load.

Can any suggest how can I get around this problem.

Edit 1:

thanks for the answer below, I am able get the functionality working using load(). But now if a image is already loaded and had been shown in the lightbox, is clicked again. the function in the load() is not called and no light box appears. any suggestions?

Edit 2:

Solution: This is what worked for me:

```
function showimage(image_path) {
    imgobj = new Image();
    imgobj.src = image_path;
    if (imgobj.complete == false)
        $(imgobj).load(function(){processimage(imgobj);});
    else
        processimage(imgobj);
}

function processimage(imgobj) {
    var aspectratio = imgobj.width/imgobj.height;
    var newht = imgobj.height;
    var newwd = imgobj.width;
    if (($(window).height() - 100) < newht) {
        newht = $(window).height() - 100;
        newwd = newht*aspectratio;
    }
    if (($(window).width() - 100) < newwd) {
        newwd = $(window).width() - 100;
        newht = newwd/aspectratio;
    }
    $('#lightbox img').attr('height', newht);
    $('#lightbox img').attr('width', newwd);
    $('#lightbox').show();
}
```

Comment: `$(window).load` will wait till all external files are downloaded... you can use that

Comment: Rather than editing the question to show how you fixed it, please accept an answer below, or add your own solution as a new answer. This makes it clearer for others that will view this question in the future, and allows your answer to be voted up/down and compared to other answers that may be given. You can even accept your own answer if it's the best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. I am reusing the image object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imgobj = new Image();
    function showimage(image_path) {
        imgobj.src = image_path;
        if (imgobj.complete == false)
            $(imgobj).load(function(){processimage(imgobj);});
        else
            processimage(imgobj);
    }

    function processimage(imgobj) {
        var aspectratio = imgobj.width/imgobj.height;
        var newht = imgobj.height;
        var newwd = imgobj.width;
        if (($(window).height() - 100) < newht) {
            newht = $(window).height() - 100;
            newwd = newht*aspectratio;
        }
        if (($(window).width() - 100) < newwd) {
            newwd = $(window).width() - 100;
            newht = newwd/aspectratio;
        }
        $('#lightbox img').attr('height', newht);
        $('#lightbox img').attr('width', newwd);
        $('#lightbox').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If u always want to access the image height and width you could take a different approach and use the jquery `hide()` and `show()` functions.

This way the images will always be loaded and you would only show them when the image is clicked thus giving the user the illusion of loading and giving you access to the height and width.

Comment: There is a huge list of images and loading all of them doesn't seems to be a good idea. Hence I have to load images after user click.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve with the width and height?
use it as it is or change it?

Comment: i have to resize the lightbox and image to fit in the window

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your function is that in your function you create a new image object, in which you then add the path, however the actual image is never loaded at that point. What you want to do is set the object, add the path and then load it:

```
   function showimage(image_path) {
        imgobj = new Image();
        imgobj.src = image_path;
        //load the image:
        $(imgobj).load(function(){
           var aspectratio = imgobj.width/imgobj.height;
           var newht = imgobj.height;
           var newwd = imgobj.width;
           if (($(window).height() - 100) < newht) {
               newht = $(window).height() - 100;
               newwd = newht*aspectratio;
           }
           if (($(window).width() - 100) < newwd) {
              newwd = $(window).width() - 100;
              newht = newwd/aspectratio;
           }
           $('#lightbox img').attr('height', newht);
           $('#lightbox img').attr('width', newwd);
           $('#lightbox').show();
        });
    }
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5d7mM/

Comment: this worked. thanks. I was using onLoad which doesn't to be working very well. But I am now facing another problem that, once a image is loaded in the lightbox and same image is click again, the load function is not called and no lightbox. any clue?

Comment: since you are loading the image into a new object, you will have to bind the click event to the image again. see jquery .bind() or jquery .on()

Comment: the problem is not with the event. The code pointer reaches till load and then there is no further processing and javascript fails to work after that and there is no error in the console.

Comment: can you show the code that is handling the click event? It would be good to see all functions that are in effect here.

Comment: I  have added the solution to the edit, I forgot to mention that I was creating the image object only once and reusing it and that was causing issue. Sorry about that :)